# Implementing a push function in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, push

I'm having some trouble with creating a push function (adding a node to the front of the list).
I know that with just a node, you could use the push function given with c++ as push_front(), but would I be able to use that here as well? :

```
struct Node {
  string val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

struct Stew {
  Node* first;
  Node* last;
};
```

Where the Stew structure is defined as having two special pointers, one pointing to the first element and one pointing to the last.
The Node structure has links in both directions.

I'm new to using these types of structures in C++ so any sort of help/hints would be greatly appreciated. I have attempted it as:

```
void push (Stew& q, string val) {

    Node *inserted = new Node();    // create a new node to be inserted in the front

    q.first -> prev = inserted;
    inserted -> next = q.first;
    inserted -> val  = q.first->val;


   }
```

Question: Do I need to initialize a head for this? Such that:

```
    Node *head = new Node();
    head -> next = NULL;
    head -> val = val;
```

Thanks for any of the help.

Comment: The only `c++` here is the use of a reference and `new`. This is `c` masquerading as `c++`.

Comment: Well.. C doesn't have references for parameters.

Comment: and references and string ... this is just fine C++.

Comment: What should be `q.first` after the `push_front` ? Why `inserted->val` is not assigned by given `val` ?

Comment: @user3358732: Grab a piece of paper and draw a list having several elements. Then draw the same list but having one more element at the front. Now look at what has changed (pointer links, item value, Stew's members) and implement it in code. Now do the same with empty list that accepts new member. If there is something new to consider - update the code. By this time you should have the answer by yourself alone.

Comment: Is this for a data structures class or learning purposes? `std::list` is quite convenient otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

```
void push (Stew& q, string val) {

    Node *inserted = new Node();

    // q.first can be NULL, so check before dereferencing it
    q.first -> prev = inserted; // Looses any node that prev was 
                                // pointing to before
    inserted -> next = q.first;
    inserted -> val  = q.first->val; // you probably meant:
                                     // inserted -> val = val;

   }
```

Comment: I may assume that `q.first` is the `head`, so no previous.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  q can be equal to NULL when the list is empty. So this statement q.first -> prev = inserted; will result in abend.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `q` is a reference actually, thus can't be `NULL`. `q.first` can be, this is another problem in the code.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I am sorry. I meant q.first.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where there is the head you are speaking about.

Of course data members `first` and `last` of an object of type `Stew` have to be initialized to `nullptr` or `NULL`.

For example

```
Stew q = {};
```

The function could look the following way

```
void push( Stew &q, const string &val ) 
{

    Node *tmp = new Node { val, q.first, nullptr };

    if ( q.first != nullptr ) q.first->prev = tmp;

    q.first = tmp;
    if ( q.last == nullptr ) q.last = q.first;
}
```

That it would be clear for you how the function works here is a simple example
**EDIT:** I added function `reverse_display` to the example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Node {
  std::string val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

struct Stew {
  Node* first;
  Node* last;
};

void push( Stew &q, const std::string &val ) 
{

    Node *tmp = new Node { val, q.first, nullptr };

    if ( q.first != nullptr ) q.first->prev = tmp;

    q.first = tmp;
    if ( q.last == nullptr ) q.last = q.first;
}

void display( const Stew &q )
{
    for ( Node *tmp = q.first; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        std::cout << tmp->val << ' ';
    }
}

void reverse_display( const Stew &q )
{
    for ( Node *tmp = q.last; tmp; tmp = tmp->prev )
    {
        std::cout << tmp->val << ' ';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    Stew q = {};

    for ( char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++ )
    {
        push( q, std::string( 1, c ) );
    }

    display( q );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    reverse_display( q );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Do not forget to write function that will delete all allocated memory for nodes.

Comment: Is it so difficult to write a comment by those who down voted?

Comment: I think it's just one guy who has pretty much downvoted every answer on this thread.

Comment: @user3264405 You are right. There are such amateurs that like to download every post.:) See my updated code with a ready to use program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `q.first` to the first node:

```
void push (Stew& q, string val) {

    Node *inserted = new Node();    // create a new node to be inserted in the front

    q.first -> prev = inserted;
    inserted -> next = q.first;
    inserted -> val  = q.first->val; //although you maybe meant inserted -> val = val;

    q.first=inserted;


   }
```

Comment: I gave him a +1 but I think it is because he loses whatever `q.first` points to? No clue. I do however prefer @πάνταῥεῖ 's solution better. No assumptions made.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames It is not specified in the question. Maybe `q.first` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of Stew, you should set the head and tail to NULL.

```
Stew s;
s.first = NULL;
s.last = NULL;
```

If you used a class instead of a struct, this would be done in the constructor.
The push function can then be

```
void push (Stew& q, string val) {

    Node *inserted = new Node();    // create a new node to be inserted in the front
    inserted->val = val;

    if (q.first == NULL) { // This list is currently empty
        // Make the inserted element the only element
        inserted->prev = NULL;
        inserted->next = NULL;
        q.first = inserted;
        q.last = inserted;
    }
    else { // The list has elements
        q.first->prev = inserted;
        inserted->next = q.first;
        inserted->prev = NULL;
        q.first = inserted;
    }
}
```

This code can be simplified a bit (redundant code removed) to

```
void push (Stew& q, string val) {
    Node *inserted = new Node();    // create a new node to be inserted in the front
    inserted->val = val;
    inserted->prev = NULL;
    inserted->next = q.first;
    q.first = inserted;
    if (q.first == NULL) { // This list is currently empty
        // Make the inserted element the only element
        q.last = inserted;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last part is the one you want as an answer — the first part doesn't add to the answer in any way.