# Printing a linked list in C++ (C++98)

Tags: c++, printing, linked-list, c++98

I'm attempting to print the nodes in a linked list (forwards direction).
It's defined as follows:

```
struct Node {
  string val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

struct Stew {
  Node* first;
  Node* last;
};
```

Where Stew has two special pointers, one pointing to the first element, and one to the last.

I'm positive that what I attempted is correct, but it's actually not.

```
void print (const Stew& q, char direction) {
  assert (!isEmpty(q));
 {
    Node* current = new Node;

    current = q.first;
    cout << current -> val;

    while((current -> next) != NULL)
    {
        current = current -> next;
        cout << (current -> val);
    }
    delete current;
}
```

I know there's a logic mistake in there, but I can't seem to pinpoint it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered debugging it, or maybe even drawing a diagram with boxes and arrows to check your operations out for correctness?

Comment: Why are you creating a new node just to print your linked list?

Comment: The best way to debug this problem is draw a picture and make pointers to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It was in the purpose of making my code clearer to show that I have another Node that's scanning through the list

Comment: Why are you deleteing nodes just to print your linked list?

Comment: In a garbage collected language the new Node would be a waste, as you immediately reassign current. In C++ in in a memory leek.

Comment: you have an extra open bracket `{`, it will not compile.

Comment: you don't need a pre-condition that the list is not empty. You can print an empty list.

Comment: @user3358732 - using "new" and "delete" does not make code clearer.  All it will do is introduce bugs, as you now have a memory leak doing the "new"/"delete" stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a push function in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075263/implementing-a-push-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you do not read answers on your question? I already showed you how to print the list in the direct and reverse order. See here.
[Implementing a push function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075263/implementing-a-push-function-in-c/22075528#22075528)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are treating your current pointer like it is an object. Current is a pointer that simply points to another object in memory. Hence your line `Node *current = new Node` is meaningless and you are losing that Node in memory. Your problem is probably the last line where you `delete current`. Current is pointing to the last item in your list and when you call delete you are freeing the memory current points to. Hence you are deleting the last object in your list. You only need to use delete when you are creating an object in memory, and current should not be a new item it should be a pointer to existing memory.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
Node* current = new Node;
```

That is totally unnecessary.  You don't want to create a new node from the heap.  All you want to do is point current node to the head node:

```
  Node* current = q.first;
```

Then assuming that current is a valid node, and the next pointer will either point to the next valid node or NULL to denote the end of the list, your while() loop is starting off wrong.  It should be something like this:

```
 while(current != NULL)
 {
    cout << current->val;
    current = current->next; 
 }
```

And of course, remove the call to "delete" at the end.